# How to display a row content in json format in node?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

am trying to fetch the data from sql server 2008 via Node using Drivers. Somehow i can get the data successfully.. My Question is how to display it in Json format.

My code is like this:

```
execSql("select * from tblStudent", function (err,rows) {

        console.log("City_StrCode:"  + rows[0].value);
        console.log("State_StrCode:"  + rows[1].value);
        console.log("City_StrName:" + rows[2].value);


});
```

Right now my results after querying the database is like this:

```
City_StrCode:0005
State_StrCode:ORS
City_StrName:Ratnagiri12
City_StrCode:1002
State_StrCode:78899
City_StrName:thousandtwo
City_StrCode:1010
State_StrCode:1001
City_StrName:U FOOL34
Status:true
City_StrCode:105
State_StrCode:001
City_StrName:dgrt12
City_StrCode:1789
State_StrCode:001
City_StrName:XZAS12
```

Suggest me something...

Comment: what means "Node using Drivers"? where do you got the execSql from? what do you mean by "json format"? if rows is an array it is a valid format and you can iterate over that array...

Comment: Am using tedious driver for connecting sql with node.

Comment: In my sql it is in table format like Name,code and it has certain amount of records. i need to display that record byeach row separatly using json kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JSON stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) has an arg to prettify and indent.  This will print and indent each level 2 spaces.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, 2);
```

So this:

```
var obj = ['one', 'two', {a:1, b:2}];
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

Outputs:

```
[
  "one",
  "two",
  {
    "a": 1,
    "b": 2
  }
]
```

If the raw object contains more data than you want or you want to be selective, or you want control on how the JSON obj to output is built, then you can copy data into a new object then pretty print that.  also note that your SQL result set is flat so mod'ing as you loop allows you to build it into objects.  Something like ...

```
execSql("select * from tblStudent", function (err,rows) {
    for (i=0; i<rows.length; i++) {
        var output;
        var fieldNum = i % 3;

        switch (fieldNum){
           case 0:
               output = {};
               output.cityCode = rows[i].value;
               break;
           case 1:
               output.stateCode = rows[i].value;
               break;
           case 2:
               output.stateName = rows[i].value;
               console.log(output, null, 2);
               break;
        }
    }


});
```

Comment: @Aarthi - I edited and edited another option to flatten out the sql result set into a custom JSON obj if you want to control what get's outputted.

Comment: Yes - that's what you asked.  Do you want an array instead of each row?  If so, don't print in case 2, instead, add to an array then outside the loop, print the array.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to log out every row as a single object do it like this

```
execSql("select * from tblStudent", function (err,rows) {

    rows.forEach(function (row) {
       console.log(row);
    });

});
```

or formatted like bryanmac proposed:

```
execSql("select * from tblStudent", function (err,rows) {

    rows.forEach(function (row) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(row, null, 2));
    });

});
```